# OnButton Click Share Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

Below is my Code :

```
    public void OnAttendLogin(View view) {
    sp = getSharedPreferences("attendlogin", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String emp_id = sp.getString("emp_id", null);
    InTImeWorker inTImeWorker = new InTImeWorker(this);
    inTImeWorker.delegate = (AsyncResponse) this;
    inTImeWorker.execute(emp_id);

    //shared pref for saving In_time in textview
    sp = getSharedPreferences("InTime", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    String in_time_sharedpref = In_time.getText().toString();
    editor.putString("in_time_sp", in_time_sharedpref);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
    out_time_button.setEnabled(true);
    in_time_button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

I want to know what wrong I am Doing in Code ?
How i can use two shared Preferences in android studio ??

Comment: _I want to know what wrong I am Doing in Code ?..._ What errors do you get?

Comment: not getting any errors ..

Comment: can i use two shared preferences inside one button click

Comment: Not with the same name though, you have used sp as the name for two shared preferences!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong that you are using same reference for both shared preference.

*Yes, you can use two shared Preference at one button click.*

Create two shared Preference object.

```
SharedPreferences sp;
SharedPreferences sp2;
SharedPreferences.Editor editorSp ;
SharedPreferences.Editor editorSp2 ;

sp = getSharedPreferences("attendlogin", MODE_PRIVATE);
sp2 = getSharedPreferences("InTime", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Final code will be like this:

```
public void OnAttendLogin(View view) {
    sp = getSharedPreferences("attendlogin", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String emp_id = sp.getString("emp_id", null);
    InTImeWorker inTImeWorker = new InTImeWorker(this);
    inTImeWorker.delegate = (AsyncResponse) this;
    inTImeWorker.execute(emp_id);

    //shared pref for saving In_time in textview
    sp2 = getSharedPreferences("InTime", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp2.edit();
    String in_time_sharedpref = In_time.getText().toString();
    editorsp2.putString("in_time_sp", in_time_sharedpref);
    editorsp2.apply();
    editorsp2.commit();
    out_time_button.setEnabled(true);
    in_time_button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: working alone on a project confuses me on the code which i am doing

Comment: Actually I want full Help in my android application .... trying hard to complete it .... but not working out @Abhishek Kumar

Comment: What issue are you getting ?

Comment: I am developing an application where i want employee to add there In_TIme and Out_time (Daily Attendance) .. Have made the application using PHP as a back end But i am not able to keep the value in the textview its not getting updated . in backend the data is saved but i am not able to show in app ..

Comment: I am using shared pref to save the session of the login and used interface to add the set the data in textview but its not working. i have made a database as well but not understanding the part how and where i can use it

Comment: Don't use session by PHP , SharedPreferences is just for save data internally on android . If you want to use multiple user on same app then go with Sqlite . All the things you can do by using JSON API.

Answer (score 0):

Use one sharedpreference name

```
"sp = getSharedPreference("attendlogin",MODE_PRIVATE);"
```

and use different different variable to save data

**example:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
String in_time_sharedpref = In_time.getText().toString();
editor.putString("in_time_sp", in_time_sharedpref);
editor.apply();
String emp_id = sp.getString("emp_id", null);
```

**i.e.** sp should be same with name ""